# Python: draw tangent graph using math & turtle libraries

Tags: python, math, turtle-graphics

I was stuck on this task for several days. Although, the solution should be simple. I apply math and turtle libraries for drawing 3 graphs: sine, cosine and tangent with amplitude 200. The problem is I cant build the tangent graph as It should be drawn. 
This is what I should do:

[image: desired graph]

This is what I got:

[image: actual result]

As you see, my turtle goes up and doesn't come back anymore. 
Pls, don't suggest me to use numpy. It's out of my task.
Thank you for advance!

```
import math
import turtle

ws = turtle.Screen()
ws.bgcolor("white")
t = turtle.Turtle()
for i in [(0,250), (0,0), (0,-250), (0,0), (400,0), (0,0)]:
    t.goto(i, None)
    t.write(i, font=("Arial", 12))

t.color("red")

for angle in range(360):
    y = math.sin(math.radians(angle))        
    t.goto(angle, y * 200)

t.penup()
t.setpos(0,200)
t.goto(0,200)
t.pendown()
t.color("blue")

for angle in range(360):
    y = math.cos(math.radians(angle))       
    t.goto(angle, y * 200)

t.penup()
t.setpos(0,0)
t.goto(0,0)
t.pendown()
t.color("green")

for angle in range(360):
    y = math.tan(math.radians(angle))
    t.goto(angle, y * 200)

ws.exitonclick()
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if edit this question to include the code that isn't producing the correct result.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thx for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that it should work, below is my minimalist implementation of plotting sine, cosine and tangent using turtle graphics:

```
import math
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

RESOLUTION = 0.1

def plot(x_points, y_points):
    for i, y in enumerate(y_points):
        if abs(y) <= 2.0:
            yertle.goto(x_points[i], y)
            yertle.pendown()
        else:
            yertle.penup()

    yertle.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, -1.5, 2 * math.pi / RESOLUTION, 1.5)

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.penup()

x = range(int(2 * math.pi / RESOLUTION))

yertle.color("blue")
plot(x, (math.cos(n * RESOLUTION) for n in x))

yertle.color("red")
plot(x, (math.sin(n * RESOLUTION) for n in x))

yertle.color("dark green")
plot(x, (math.tan(n * RESOLUTION) for n in x))

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

My guess is you're not waiting long enough for tangent to plot, i.e. it's slowly plotting lots of points off the window and will eventually reappear on-screen.  My code works around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

try about this. Near to work for me, no time to get better:

for angle in range(360):
    y=0

```
y = math.tan(math.radians(angle))
if y<1 and y>-1:
    t.goto(angle, y * 200)
```

Comment: What does `for angle in range(360): y=0` do?

Answer (score 0):

With asipmtotas

```
for angle in range(360):
    t.penup()
    y = math.tan(math.radians(angle))

    if y<1 and y>-1:
        t.pendown()
        t.goto(angle, y * 200)
    else:
        t.penup()
        #t.pendown()
        t.goto(angle, 200)
```