# What is an ideal range for making tan graph so it fits in my screen?

Tags: python, graph, scale, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I've been trying making tangent graph using python turtle but I am not able to get an ideal value to make get the values on tan graphs fit in my screen. Please let me know a good value for tan graph. Please refer to my code:

```
import turtle 
import math

wn = turtle.Screen()
turt = turtle.Turtle()
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(90)
t.write(' π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.forward(90)
t.write(' π ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.forward(90)
t.write(' 3π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.forward(90)
t.write(' 2π ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(360)
t.write((0,0),font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.left(90)
t.forward(100)
t.write((0,1),font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.forward(100)
t.write((0,2),font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(300)
t.write((0,-1),font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(100)
t.write((0,-2),font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.forward(200)
t.right(90)
t.backward(90)
t.write(' -π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(90)
t.write(' -π ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(90)
t.write(' -3π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(90)
t.write(' -2π ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
for x in range(-360,360):
    turt.goto(x, math.tan(math.radians(x)) * 100)
wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: There is no way to make a graph of `tan(x)` fit on the screen.  If the x axis range includes at least a full cycle of the function, then the y axis range includes both positive and negative infinity.

Comment: This might give you some idea of [how to display tangent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43165204/5771269) using turtle.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you lessen down the tangent line's y scale from 100 to a small number like `5`, and then you can scale down the coordinates of the grid accordingly:

```
for x in range(-360,360):
    turt.goto(x, math.tan(math.radians(x)) * 5)
```